# How can I remove the raw type warning in eclipse from this code?

Tags: java, java-6

I currently suppress the nagging from eclipse about the use of raw types in this snippet

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
List doSomething(Integer arg1, ...) {
    ....
}
```

I am actually returning a raw type `List` generated from an old version of Hibernate. Is there any way to change this API to return:

```
List<Object[]>
```

Do I just cast the List to the above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually replace a raw `List` with a `List<?>`.

If you know specifically that the items are `Object[]`, you can simply cast

```
List<Object[]> doSomething(Integer arg1, ...) {
    List rawList = ...
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Object[]> cookedList = (List<Object[]>)rawList;
    return cookedList;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the method signature to:

```
List<Object> doSomething(Integer arg1, ...) {
    ....
}
```

With ***no*** negative impact to any calling client. Of course, this just removes the need for using the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation on that method itself. It does nothing for all the warnings you must be getting in other parts of your code that are using raw versions of the `List` class.